# Why can I send e-mails with Amazon SES only to verified e-mail addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp

I verified a domain and a single e-mail address on that domain in Amazon SES.

When using the "Send test email" function or trying to send e-mails via SMTP I can only send mails TO that one verified e-mail address.

This is not really helpful. How can I send e-mails to any other e-mail address from Amazon SES?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m guessing it’s due to being in the Amazon SES sandbox.

According to [this AWS page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-addresses-and-domains.html), To addresses also need to be verified if you’re within the sandbox.